# Декларация и реализация шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Потребовалось создать шаблон, делал все как обычно принято в C/C++, сначала декларацию в header файле, а потом и реализацию в cpp файле, разумеется были ошибки линкинга, позже мне пояснили, что так нельзя и нужно реализацию делать в header файле, но проблема в том, что если я ее сделаю в header файле, то у меня будут ошибки:

> incomplete type ‘...’ used in nested name specifier

Вот мой код в упрощенном виде:
a.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "b.h"

class A {
public:
    static A *test(A *q) {
        return q;
    };
};
```

b.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "a.h"

class A;

template <typename T = A>
T *test2(T *arg);
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

template <typename T = A>
T *test2(T *arg) {
    return (T *)A::test(arg);
}
```

c.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main() {
    A q;
    test2(&q);
    return 0;
}
```

Тут будут проблемы с линкингом ибо шаблон реализован неправильно, но если перенести реализацию шаблона из b.cpp в b.h, то ошибка уже будет такая:

> In file included from a.h:3:0,
>                    from c.cpp:1: b.h: In function ‘T* test2(T*)’: b.h:8:20: error: incomplete type ‘A’ used in nested name specifier
>        return (T *)A::test(arg);

Выходит патовая ситуация, как ее можно разрешить?(без использования extern templates, они неподходят по нескольким причинам)

Comment: Зачем в `a.h` инклюдить `b.h`, зачем в `b.h` инклюдить `a.h` и одновременно объявлять `A`? c-style кастование тоже ни к чему.

Comment: тут слишком упрощенно и не зачем, но в реальной ситуации требуется и это изменить не как нельзя, потребуется кардинально менять многое, а кода там немало

Comment: Во первых нельзя любой указатель преобразовать в любой другой...

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял что вы хотите, если честно.

Но вот так работает:

A.h:

```
#pragma once

class A
{
public:
    static A* test(A* q){
        return q;
    }
};
```

b.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "a.h"


template <typename T = A>
T *test2(T *arg){
    return T::test(arg);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    A q;
    test2(&q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: код не соответствует моему, то есть его логика изменена, в  b.h должен быть вызов A::test, ну и в a.h должен включатся файл b.h

Comment: @ВіталійКарпенко А зачем вам в a.h включать b.h ?
У вас в a.h в классе A статичный метод `test`, а в b.h шаблонная функция, принимающая некий класс, у которого должен быть статичный метод `test`, и по-умолчанию вы делаете параметр шаблона равным классу A, то есть при вызове шаблонной функции без явного указания типа вызовется A::test, в чем проблема ?

Comment: я уже ответил на это в комментарии, тут код слишком упрощен, но в реальности требуется и изменить это нельзя

Comment: @ВіталійКарпенко  Мне всё равно ничего не понятно.  То есть вам нужна шаблонная функция, внутри которой всегда вызывается некоторая другая функция всегда возвращающая указатель на конкретный класс, но кастовать вы её хотите к чему угодно, хоть к `int*`, я правильно понял ? А шаблон тогда зачем ? Сделайте `dynamic_cast` к нужному типу вручную там где вам это нужно по коду. Либо сделайте пример более подробным, либо я даже не знаю что ещё предложить.

Comment: @ВіталійКарпенко 
`но в реальной ситуации требуется и это изменить не как нельзя`
`в реальности требуется и изменить это нельзя` 
Если вы имеете в виду что требуется чтобы в a.h включался b.h, в b.h включался a.h, в шаблонной функции всегда вызывался конкретный метод конкретного класса (который в этом примере можно и просто вынести в отдельную функцию, вы ничего не делаете в статичном методе), то добавьте это куда-нибудь в вопрос. Хотя странновато как-то получается.

Comment: подробности: static A* test - https://github.com/s1lentq/ReGameDLL_CS/blob/master/regamedll/dlls/cbase.h#L162 template <typename T = A> T *test2(T *arg) - https://github.com/s1lentq/ReGameDLL_CS/blob/master/regamedll/dlls/util.h#L314

Comment: вынос статической функции мне не подходит, мне нужно так как есть сейчас или если так нельзя, то я просто откажусь от шаблонов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76243/discussion-between-vegorov-and--).